# "Insufficient Storage Error" when updating and Downloading

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, google

My question is probably the same as many other questions like "Fix Google Play insufficient storage error without rooting my phone", and similar to that one, i want to do it without rooting my phone. I've used cache clearing apps, uninstalling google play updates and clearing the data and cache from it, but to no avail.

I have about 6 GB of free SD card space and about 250 MB of free internal storage. I use an Alcatel One Touch Pop Icon. 
Build version: 6G1M-UDM2

The funny thing is, it's only with these apps. I can update my other apps, I can even download new apps!

I'm seriously confused and can't find anything else on the web that relates to my problem. Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*EDIT: Never mind, everything can't download or update, so hopefully the new info helps.

Comment: Better way is to root your device and use LinkToSD app, hence you'll be able to install more apps and integrate new updates over the apps...May be there is any other way... so good luck